# SQL Like with column containing wildcards

Tags: sql, sql-server

So in my DB I have a column of business rules

```
NAMEMUSTBELIKE

%%

%DICK%

%GOLF%
```

And I want to query where 'DICK SPORTING GOODS' matches rows %% and %DICK%

I tried 'DICK SPORTING GOODS' Like [NAMEMUSTBELIKE] but that doesn't work.

My current query is

```
SELECT [NAMEMUSTBELIKE]
  FROM [powerappPlan].[dbo].[TestReverseLike]
  where 'DICK SPORTING GOODS' like [NAMEMUSTBELIKE]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post the entire query

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with `WHERE 'DICK SPORTING GOODS' LIKE [NAMEMUSTBELIKE];`...

Comment: What field type is NAMEMUSTBELIKE?  If CHAR, it looks like the trailing spaces might be an issue.

Comment: @BlueGI its NCHAR so you may be on to something let me trim it first

Comment: Post the DDL and DLM of your table, not a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was NCHAR I had to do RTtrim thanks to @BlueGI

```
SELECT *
  FROM [powerappPlan].[dbo].[TestReverseLike]
  where 'DICK SPORTING GOODS' like RTrim([NAMEMUSTBELIKE])
```

Comment: Why not use `nvarchar` instead? You should only really be using `(n)char` if every string has the same fixed width. That is clearly not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT '%%' AS NAMEMUSTBELIKE INTO tab UNION ALL
SELECT '%DICK%' UNION ALL
SELECT '%GOLF%';

SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE 'DICK SPORTING GOODS'  LIKE Namemustbelike;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=73652d052e1b1036b5d9c8e98b112ef0)**